# What is this exponential distribution called?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The symmetric Dirichlet distribution is given by:

$P(X)=Z\prod{{x_i}^{\lambda-1}}$

where $Z$ is a normalization factor, $x_i\geq0$, and $\sum x_i=1$.

I am wondering about the following related distribution, where we replace $x_i$ with $e^{x_i}$:

$P(X)=Z\prod{e^{x_i(\lambda-1)}}$

where again $Z$ is a normalization factor, $x_i\geq0$, and $\sum x_i=1$.

Does the following distribution have a name? What is known about it (does it occur naturally somewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X)=Z\prod e^{x_i(\lambda-1)}=Ze^{(\lambda-1)\sum x_i}=Ze^{\lambda-1}$, so this distribution is constant, and therefore uniform, over the region $\{X:x_i\ge 0,\sum_i x_i=1\}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed not an interesting case. But what happens if you remove the constraint $sum{x_i}=1$?

Comment: In that case, the pdf of X is a product of several factors where the $i^th$ factor only depends on $x_i$. Therefore, the components are independent. Each component is exponential with parameter $1-\lambda$. The distribution would only be well defined if this parameter is positive.

Comment: Thanks - do you know if this has a name? or is it simply a multivariate exponential distribution?

Comment: I don’t think it has a special name. There’s no need to give it a name since you can refer to X as an iid list of exponentials.